# What is wrong with this code? Getting a unexpected symbol override

Tags: unity-game-engine

When trying to compile the following code, the compiler is saying the following:

**Unexpected symbol override**

Can someone help with diagnosing the issue? The code seems as though it should work based on my research on other websites and forums, but I don't know where to begin trying to solve the issue.

```
UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Reload : StateMachineBehaviour {

    public float reloadTime = 0.7f;
    bool hasReloaded = false

     // OnStateEnter is called when a transition starts and the state machine starts to evaluate this state
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
        hasReloaded = false;


    }

    // OnStateUpdate is called on each Update frame between OnStateEnter and OnStateExit callbacks
    override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
        if (hasReloaded) return;

        if(stateInfo.normalizedTime >= reloadTime)
        {
            animator.GetComponent<pyssy>().Reload();
            hasReloaded = true;
        }
    }

    // OnStateExit is called when a transition ends and the state machine finishes evaluating this state
    override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
        hasReloaded = false;

    }

    // OnStateMove is called right after Animator.OnAnimatorMove(). Code that processes and affects root motion should be implemented here
    //override public void OnStateMove(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
    //
    //}

    // OnStateIK is called right after Animator.OnAnimatorIK(). Code that sets up animation IK (inverse kinematics) should be implemented here.
    //override public void OnStateIK(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
    //
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing your code, it does seem like it will fail to compile due to at least one syntax error.

I see that you're missing a semicolon here:

`bool hasReloaded = false`

Next, the following if-block is doing a `GetComponent` for a class called `pyssy`.

I'm not sure if that's a typo or not. But it doesn't seem like a helpful class name to me.

**Nonetheless, this is more of just a note. 
The missing semicolon is likely the issue related to your current `Unexpect symbol override` error.**